# Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Scaffold-DbContext when using named connection from appsetting

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 class library to `Scaffold-DbContext` to reverse engineering the tables into models.

It is throwing an error

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

if I use the connection string directly instead of `-Connection` it work without problem, but trying to understand what is that I am not doing correctly?

```
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DatabaseConsString": "Server=tcp:mysqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mysqldb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }
}
```

The above is my appsetting.json file, and this is the command I use:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext -Connection Name=DatabaseConsString 
             Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir DbModels 
             -Context myDbContext -UseDatabaseNames -Force 
             -Tables [dbo].[UserInfo],[dbo].[Transactions]

    Build started...
    Build succeeded.
```

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
>
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
>
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
>
>   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
>
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
>
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>
>   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Comment: dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=SERVER\INSTANCE;Integrated Security=True;Database="DATABASE"" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models\Database --context-dir Database\DBContext --schema "dbo" -d --no-pluralize -f